# java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid cursor state

Tags: java, sql, database

I created a simple application that compares a database value with a textfield value, but when I execute the project it gives me the following `Exception`:

> `java.sql.SQLException`: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid cursor state

This is the code I'm using:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   String dataSource ="testDb";
   String U="jdbc:odbc:"+dataSource;
   try {
      Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
      Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(U,"","");

      PreparedStatement s=con.prepareStatement("Select * from student");
      ResultSet s1=s.executeQuery();


      String textField;
      textField=jTextField1.getText();
      String database =s1.getString(1);
      if(textField.equals(database)) { 
         System.out.println("ok");
      } else {
         System.out.println("Not ok");
      }
   } catch(Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("THE EXCEPTION IS"+ex);
   }
}
```

What could be the cause if this `Exception`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do `s.executeQuery()`, the initial position of the [`ResultSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) is **BEFORE** the first row.

You have to do `rs.next()` to advance it to the first row.

Enclose your `ResultSet` processing in a `if ( s1.next() ) {}` block

Answer (score 0):

you need to make Resultset pointer to the first row by using next function and then make the compare that you need between the database value and the textField value 
i hope this helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this..

```
        ResultSet s1=s.executeQuery();
        String database=null;
        if(s1.next())
        {
          database =s1.getString(1);
        }
```

- When **s1.getString(1)** is used without  **s1.next()**.
- **s1** is not pointing to first row.That's why the exception