# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid cursor state

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

Guys Here's what I am having. The current error is

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid cursor state
```

and this is the piece of work thats causing the error

```
String query3 = "SELECT Last(threadID) AS thread2 FROM msthread";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query3); 
rs.getString("thread2");
```

The result of that query is only to return 1 column and 1 row, ran it through MSAccess and it showed exactly what I wanted to see.

```
This is exactly what it looks like:    
thread2
43
```

But now I kept getting the Invalid Cursor State error. I have no idea why.

Thanks for the help guys

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.sql.SQLException: \[Microsoft\]\[ODBC Driver Manager\] Invalid cursor state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391876/java-sql-sqlexception-microsoftodbc-driver-manager-invalid-cursor-state)

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `next()` on the `ResultSet` before you can retrieve values.

So use:

```
if (rs.next()) {
    rs.getString("thread2");
}
```

(or a `while` loop)

Comment: Correct answer. See the JavaDoc for more details: `A ResultSet object maintains a cursor pointing to its current row of data. Initially the cursor is positioned before the first row. etc.`